# Update AdMob SDK Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2, admob

I tried removing an old SDK from my xcode swift project and it does not seem to be working. I deleted the framework, downloaded the most recent and added/linked it to the project.  is still telling me I should update it in the log and Im not sure how to properly do this. I searched everywhere with no luck.

Comment: Ones clean your project. Than try to run. And have you changed the google services file.?

Comment: What do you mean clean?

Comment: Command key + shift + K